# How can I run  "update-manager-kde"

Tags: 11.10, kde, update-manager

How to make update-manager-kde work. It doesn't show on any menus. Typing: "update-manager-kde"in the terminal didn't do the trick either.

Comment: Do you try tiping 'sudo update manager kde'?

Comment: yes,but it still didn't work

Comment: What error does it print when you type `update-manager-kde`?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such executable as `update-manager-kde` (though there is a package with such name).

The correct executable name for Kubuntu's update manager is now `muon-updater`.